# Delay crone trigger (diffrent first start date) in quartz

Tags: c#, nhibernate, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I've almost finished simple application in c# with quartz which run some SQL queries periodically.

I have a question, is it possible to create cron trigger which start job at specific date and after this date do some jobs periodically.

here is my code:

```
                    IJobDetails myJob = new JobDetails(); //This Constructor needs to be parameterless i nic na to nie poradzimy
                    JobDetailImpl jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl(name, gruoupName, myJob.GetType());
                    //dodawanie parametru
                    jobDetail.JobDataMap.Add("addParam", item);
                    //////
                    CronTriggerImpl trigger = new CronTriggerImpl();
                    trigger.Name = triggerName;
                    trigger.Group = grupa;
                    trigger.CronExpressionString = "0 10 14-15 8 8 ?";

                    try
                    {
                        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("INVALID TRIGGER. JOB CANCELED");
                    }
                    DateTimeOffset? nextFireTime = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc().Value.AddHours(2);

                    Console.WriteLine("Job o jobs_id=" + item.jobs_id + " start:" +     nextFireTime.Value);
```

For example: 
Today is 1.08.2013 and today i want to create crone trigger which start at 8.08.2013 and fires SQL query every day from 2:00pm to 3:00pm every 10minutes.

At the moment I know how to make crone trigger which start 8.08.2013 and run once, and know how to create second crone trigger which run every day from 2:00pm to 3:00pm every 10minutes but i still can not figure out how to marge this 2 crone triggers and create one: which start at 8.08.2013, run everyday after  8.08.2013 and fires SQL query every day from 2:00pm to 3:00pm for each 10minutes.

I tried use:

```
      trigger.FinalFireTimeUtc(someDate);
      trigger.SetNextFireTimeUtc(someDate)
```

But without any positive result. Job fires as its cronExpressionString says.

Many thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You lenimall for answer. I check method StatTimeUTC but it returns start datetime value, not setting it. I have found blog which proffs Quartz is not capable of running jobs at the time when you desired.
http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html
Anyway, many thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

The key is when building your Trigger use the 'StartAt' extension method.

```cs
/* calculate the next time you want your job to run - in this case top of the next hour */
var hourFromNow = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
var topOfNextHour = new DateTime(hourFromNow.Year, hourFromNow.Month, hourFromNow.Day, hourFromNow.Hour, 0, 0);

/* build your trigger and call 'StartAt' */
TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("Delayed Job").WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(60).RepeatForever()).StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(topOfNextHour))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Quartz.net you're using, but there is a "StartTimeUtc" property you can set with 2.0. You might want to try that one.

Comment: StartDateUtc has no setter unfortunately - atleast as of 2.2.4 (possibly earlier)